# Click event on any part of the window with pygtk.Window

Tags: python, pygtk

I am using pygtk with glade to make a simple program which (by now) consists on:

GUI:
A grid 4x4, each one showing an name.
Under the grid  goes a text Entry.
The program runs in fullscreen.

BEHAVIOR:
Each name will be "selectable" for 10secs in an infinite loop. "selectable" means that wherever the user makes a click the name which 10secs time is running is selected and put on the TextEntry.

I already made the GUI, but don't know how to handle it for detecting the click anywhere on the screen. Any help?

Comment: By using the "clicked" signal of the widget that is clicked ? (Note that some widgets have also a "selected" signal.)

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter which widget is clicked, just that a click was made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect a click anywhere on the screen you can connect a callback for the [`button-press-event`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--button-press-event). Note that this is a `gdk` event and you must add this event to the mask with the [`add_events`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--add-events) method.

The following small program should be useful:

```
import gtk

def callback(window, event):
    assert event.type == gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS
    print 'Clicked at x={0}, y={0}'.format(event.x, event.y)

window = gtk.Window()
window.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
window.connect('button-press-event', callback)
window.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Comment: this is definitely usefull, thanks a lot. I am new with pygtk and glade. Where could I find more information about 'button-press-event', BUTTON_PRESS_MARK and related-stuff? I have a lot to learn. By example, I will also need to manage the double-click event

Comment: pyGTK is well documented. Take a look at http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/ and http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html

Comment: @jeanc Please have a look at the links in may answer. With regard to double click, you will need a different gdk mask: `gtk.gdk._2BUTTON_PRESS`. The complete list of `gdk` event type constans is [here](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gdk-constants.html#gdk-event-type-constants).

Comment: @jcollado is there a trick to work with textviews? I have one in my window and when the click is in that area, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @jeanc If you use the same `add_events` and `connect` calls for the text views, your callback will be executed also when the mouse is clicked over them.

Comment: @jcollado I was reviewing my old questions and realized that hadn't answered your last comment, sorry. It works perfectly

Comment: The details of API here may seem outdated for [current versions of python gtk](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#simple-example)